# How to iterate through the elements in a JSON array?

Tags: arrays, json, delphi

From an API, I receive a JSON object with this syntax:

```json
{"returnValue":
 ["[State;"
 ,[{"ajourDate":20210901, "customernr":123, "customernavn":"PartyMix"}
  ,{"ajourDate":20210825, "customernr":124, "customernavn":"DinnerShop"}
  ,{"ajourDate":20210811, "customernr":125, "customernavn":"CosyCorner"}
  ,{"ajourDate":20210910, "customernr":126, "customernavn":"The Coffee Shop"}
  ]
 ]
,"returnOutparameters":[]
,"exception":null
}
```

I need to iterate through this output and handle every element in the array
containing the customer information.

I'm using Delphi 2009 and 10.4 (both Enterprise versions), and [JsonDataObjects](https://github.com/ahausladen/JsonDataObjects) when generating my REST Request.

Answer (score 1):

The front page of the Git repo: [ahausladen / JsonDataObjects](https://github.com/ahausladen/JsonDataObjects#json-data-objects) has this example:

```
var
  Obj: TJsonObject;
begin
  Obj := TJsonObject.Parse('{ "foo": "bar", "array": [ 10, 20 ] }') as TJsonObject;
  try
    ShowMessage(Obj['foo']);
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Obj['array'].Count));
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Obj['array'].Items[0]));
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Obj['array'].Items[1]));
  finally
    Obj.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Other examples show accessing sub objects / arrays.